# pandas cumcount in pyspark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

Currently attempting to convert a script I made from pandas to pyspark, I have a dataframe that contains data in the form of:

```
index | letter
------|-------
0     | a
1     | a
2     | b
3     | c
4     | a
5     | a
6     | b
```

I want to create the following dataframe in which the occurrence count for each instance of a letter is stored, for example the first time we see "a" its occurrence count is 0, second time 1, third time 2:

```
index | letter | occurrence
------|--------|-----------
0     | a      | 0
1     | a      | 1
2     | b      | 0
3     | c      | 0
4     | a      | 2
5     | a      | 3
6     | b      | 1
```

I can achieve this in pandas using:

`df['occurrence'] = df.groupby('letter').cumcount()`

How would I go about doing this in pyspark? Cannot find an existing method that is similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called [window functions](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df.withColumn("occurence", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("letter").orderBy("index")))
```

Comment: Thank you, will test this out now.